# Doubts on Rspec feature when user_id is needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Say I want to test that a User is able to fill a form to create a new project.  The route that I need to visit is: `new_user_project_path(:user_id)`.

So, my feature rspec looks like this right now:

```
feature "User creates a project" do
  scenario "Logged in User creates a project" do
    login_with_oauth #this sets current_user
    visit new_user_project_path 
    fill_in 'Title', :with => 'Colchasdadasdasoneta'
    fill_in 'Description', :with => 'lalalssalsalas'
    click_in 'Create Project'
  end
end
```

As you can tell, I can't use this visit new_user_project_path because it needs a :user_id to be passed. My question is, how can I access the current_user? Or what is the correct way of testing this kind of stuff?

Comment: when you login_with_oauth, do you specify a user or user_id?

Comment: HM1, nop. It's facebook omniauth login...

Answer (score 1):

Your routes have problem. Instead of fixing the problem directly which is easy, better to double check your code logic.

You should not define user id as path param to create a new project. Instead, the project instance should be initiated by current_user.

To associate a new project with user, just do it in controller

```
@project = current_user.projects.new
```

In conclusion:

1. Change the controller code similar to above
2. Restore your routes to conventional resource.
3. Then, use your test as it is, though a bit more expectations should be appended.

Comment: Interesting. I thought it was "Restful" to have /users/:user_id/projects. I mean, imagine that I want to test the ability of seeing all the projects associated with a User. The route would ideally be /users/:user_id/projects (index action) right?

Comment: @HommerSmith, what you mentioned is polymorphic url which is also a conventional solution in some cases. However it's nothing to do with the question we talked here. In the question you exposed user id in url for building a project instance(in #new), if simple form, no big problem, if the form need to get some user private information, your code exposed them to public as everybody can reach this url by appending an user id. Further more, in #create and #update, if you continue this practice, you let all users to create and update project for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `login_with_oauth` is a spec helper method that you wrote, you can have that return the user that it setup. Then you can do:

```
feature "User creates a project" do
  scenario "Logged in User creates a project" do
    user = login_with_oauth
    visit new_user_project_path(user)
```

If that doesn't work, and `login_with_oauth` is something you don't control (say it comes from some library), you can fetch the first user out of the database. This is assuming no other users are in the db, but there shouldn't be because your tests should be clean and autonomous. Then do:

```
feature "User creates a project" do
  scenario "Logged in User creates a project" do
    login_with_oauth
    user = User.first
    visit new_user_project_path(user)
```

Comment: and then someones guesses some user ids and creates projects in their name :)